# Early-mid 2010s sci-fi graphic novel about a train you could get on to leave an underground world

Tags: story-identification, novel, comics, steampunk

I read this around 2014-15. It was a black and white(?) graphic novel, taking place in an underground steampunk-esque world. The main focus of the graphic novel was on a train that you could get a ticket to in order to leave that underground world.

I think the title was one or two words and I remember the graphic novel’s cover being all black, with the name being red and embossed. I think there was a picture of the train and a character on the cover. This is about as much as I remember.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Was the graphic novel new(ish) or old when you read it? In what language did you read it? Was it a translation? What was the format (hardcover trade paperback, large, etc.)? Was it stand-alone or part of a series?

Comment: sorry for the late response 1. it was newish , wasnt old 2. it was in english 3. it was hardcover 4. it was part of a series but i only remember one other book, which had green lettering on the front, embossed as well